# How to Add Confirm Password Field In WooCommerce Registration Page?

Tags: wordpress

Am trying to add the code

```
<?php
// Add the code below to your theme's functions.php file to add a confirm password field on the register form under My Accounts.
add_filter('woocommerce_registration_errors', 'registration_errors_validation', 10,3);
function registration_errors_validation($reg_errors, $sanitized_user_login, $user_email) {
    global $woocommerce;
    extract( $_POST );
    if ( strcmp( $password, $password2 ) !== 0 ) {
        return new WP_Error( 'registration-error', __( 'Passwords do not match.', 'woocommerce' ) );
    }
    return $reg_errors;
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_register_form', 'wc_register_form_password_repeat' );
function wc_register_form_password_repeat() {
    ?>
    <p class="form-row form-row-wide">
        <label for="reg_password2"><?php _e( 'Password Repeat', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input type="password" class="input-text" name="password2" id="reg_password2" value="<?php if ( ! empty( $_POST['password2'] ) ) echo esc_attr( $_POST['password2'] ); ?>" />
    </p>
    <?php
}
?>
```

on function.php but not working... Any on tell how to add the password conformation field on woocommerce/myaccout/form-login.php

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As a follow up to [John's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39079966/7311767):

Hooking to `woocommerce_checkout_init` no longer works in Woocommerce 3.x, as they introduced a magic getter that will only return the original `$checkout->checkout_fields['account']` field, without `account2`. I don't know if this is a feature or a bug.

For Woocommerce 3.x, the correct way to do it is to use a filter. The validation stays the same.

```
// Add a second password field to the checkout page in WC 3.x.
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'wc_add_confirm_password_checkout', 10, 1 );
function wc_add_confirm_password_checkout( $checkout_fields ) {
    if ( get_option( 'woocommerce_registration_generate_password' ) == 'no' ) {
        $checkout_fields['account']['account_password2'] = array(
                'type'              => 'password',
                'label'             => __( 'Confirm password', 'woocommerce' ),
                'required'          => true,
                'placeholder'       => _x( 'Confirm Password', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce' )
        );
    }

    return $checkout_fields;
}

// Check the password and confirm password fields match before allow checkout to proceed.
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_validation', 'wc_check_confirm_password_matches_checkout', 10, 2 );
function wc_check_confirm_password_matches_checkout( $posted ) {
    $checkout = WC()->checkout;
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() && ( $checkout->must_create_account || ! empty( $posted['createaccount'] ) ) ) {
        if ( strcmp( $posted['account_password'], $posted['account_password2'] ) !== 0 ) {
            wc_add_notice( __( 'Passwords do not match.', 'woocommerce' ), 'error' );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

inside your function.php you can do this :

```
// Add a second password field to the checkout page.
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_init', 'wc_add_confirm_password_checkout', 10, 1 );
function wc_add_confirm_password_checkout( $checkout ) {
    if ( get_option( 'woocommerce_registration_generate_password' ) == 'no' ) {
        $checkout->checkout_fields['account']['account_password2'] = array(
            'type'              => 'password',
            'label'             => __( 'Confirm password', 'woocommerce' ),
            'required'          => true,
            'placeholder'       => _x( 'Confirm Password', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce' )
        );
    }
}
// Check the password and confirm password fields match before allow checkout to proceed.
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_validation', 'wc_check_confirm_password_matches_checkout', 10, 2 );
function wc_check_confirm_password_matches_checkout( $posted ) {
    $checkout = WC()->checkout;
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() && ( $checkout->must_create_account || ! empty( $posted['createaccount'] ) ) ) {
        if ( strcmp( $posted['account_password'], $posted['account_password2'] ) !== 0 ) {
            wc_add_notice( __( 'Passwords do not match.', 'woocommerce' ), 'error' );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    <?php
// Add the code below to your theme's functions.php file to add a confirm password field on the register form under My Accounts.
add_filter('woocommerce_registration_errors', 'registration_errors_validation', 10,3);
function registration_errors_validation($reg_errors, $sanitized_user_login, $user_email) {
    global $woocommerce;
    extract( $_POST );
    if ( strcmp( $password, $password2 ) !== 0 ) {
        return new WP_Error( 'registration-error', __( 'Passwords do not match.', 'woocommerce' ) );
    }
    return $reg_errors;
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_register_form', 'wc_register_form_password_repeat' );
function wc_register_form_password_repeat() {
    ?>
    <p class="form-row form-row-wide">
        <label for="reg_password2"><?php _e( 'Password Repeat', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input type="password" class="input-text" name="password2" id="reg_password2" value="<?php if ( ! empty( $_POST['password2'] ) ) echo esc_attr( $_POST['password2'] ); ?>" />
    </p>
    <?php
}
?>
```

> source : [you can find this code here i test before on my website](https://www.themelocation.com/add-confirm-password-woocommerce/#codesyntax_1)

Answer (score 2):

After so much effort, finally worked the following code with revised a little bit as per my requirement to display Confirm password in my account page. Please try the following code in functions.php

```
// Add the code below to your theme's functions.php file to add a confirm password field on the register form under My Accounts.
add_filter('woocommerce_registration_errors', 'registration_errors_validation', 10,3);
function registration_errors_validation($reg_errors, $sanitized_user_login, $user_email) {
    global $woocommerce;
    extract( $_POST );
    if ( strcmp( $password, $password2 ) !== 0 ) {
        return new WP_Error( 'registration-error', __( 'Passwords do not match.', 'woocommerce' ) );
    }
    return $reg_errors;
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_register_form', 'wc_register_form_password_repeat' );
function wc_register_form_password_repeat() {
    ?>
    <div class="form-row form-row-wide  addtafterpassword" style=" margin-top: 20px;    margin-bottom: 0;">
        <label for="reg_password2"><?php _e( 'Password Repeat', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input type="password" class="input-text" name="password2" id="reg_password2" value="<?php if ( ! empty( $_POST['password2'] ) ) echo esc_attr( $_POST['password2'] ); ?>" />
    </div>
    <?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

here Two Method one for Checkout and second for My Account below i mentioned both code

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_init', 'wc_add_confirm_password_checkout', 10, 1 );
function wc_add_confirm_password_checkout( $checkout ) {
    if ( get_option( 'woocommerce_registration_generate_password' ) == 'no' ) {
        $checkout->checkout_fields['account']['account_password2'] = array(
            'type'      => 'password',
            'label'     => __( 'Confirm password', 'woocommerce' ),
            'required'      => true,
            'placeholder'   => _x( 'Confirm Password', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce' )
        );
    }
}
// Check the password and confirm password fields match before allow checkout to proceed.
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_validation', 'wc_check_confirm_password_matches_checkout', 10, 2 );
function wc_check_confirm_password_matches_checkout( $posted ) {
    $checkout = WC()->checkout;
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() && ( $checkout->must_create_account || ! empty( $posted['createaccount'] ) ) ) {
        if ( strcmp( $posted['account_password'], $posted['account_password2'] ) !== 0 ) {
            wc_add_notice( __( 'Passwords do not match.', 'woocommerce' ), 'error' );
        }
    }
}

add_filter('woocommerce_registration_errors', 'registration_errors_validation', 10,3);
function registration_errors_validation($reg_errors, $sanitized_user_login, $user_email) {
    global $woocommerce;
    extract( $_POST );
    if ( strcmp( $password, $password2 ) !== 0 ) {
        return new WP_Error( 'registration-error', __( 'Passwords do not match.', 'woocommerce' ) );
    }
    return $reg_errors;
}
```

#

My Account Page

#

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_register_form', 'wc_register_form_password_repeat' );
function wc_register_form_password_repeat() {
    ?>
    <p class="form-row form-row-wide">
        <label for="reg_password2"><?php _e( 'Password Repeat', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input type="password" class="input-text" name="password2" id="reg_password2" value="<?php if ( ! empty( $_POST['password2'] ) ) echo esc_attr( $_POST['password2'] ); ?>" />
    </p>
    <?php
}
```