# How to add more column in the register page?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, plugins

I have used WordPress and I am on the register page and I want one more field called `confirmpassword` and I tried the below code and it's displaying the fields.

Now I try to fill in the details and clicked on submit button my page got to refresh and nothing is happening. Evening validation is also not working on confirm password.

I have unchecked `When creating an account, automatically generate an account password`

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_register_form', 'misha_add_register_form_field' );
 
function misha_add_register_form_field(){
 
    woocommerce_form_field(
        'confirmpassword',
        array(
            'type'        => 'password',
            'required'    => true, // just adds an "*"
            'label'       => 'Confirm Password',
            'placeholder' => 'Enter the confirm password'
        ),
        ( isset($_POST['confirmpassword']) ? $_POST['confirmpassword'] : '' )
    );
 
}


add_action( 'woocommerce_register_post', 'confirmpassword_validate_fields', 10, 3 );
 
function confirmpassword_validate_fields( $username, $email, $errors ) {
 
    if ( empty( $_POST['confirmpassword'] ) ) {
        $errors->add( 'confirmpassword_error', 'We really want to know!' );
    }
 
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_created_customer', 'confirmpassword_save_register_fields' );
 
function confirmpassword_save_register_fields( $customer_id ){
 
    if ( isset( $_POST['confirmpassword'] ) ) {
        update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'confirmpassword', wc_clean( $_POST['confirmpassword'] ) );
    }
 
}
```

What can I try in order to resolve this?

I refer to this link:

https://rudrastyh.com/woocommerce/add-registration-form-field.html

Comment: Read and understand: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/ … Then the right template to override is: [`myaccount/form-login.php`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4.9.2/templates/myaccount/form-login.php)

Comment: Yes, I know that. I have created separate login and registered. My issue is only confirmed password... if I add then registration not working

Comment: @LoicTheAztec, I refered to this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65897369/how-to-show-the-login-and-register-form-on-two-different-pages-with-woocommerce

Comment: @LoicTheAztec, any more help in this?

Comment: You can find more information here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37521965/how-to-add-confirm-password-field-in-woocommerce-registration-page/45818768. Furthermore, the `confirmpassword` field should only be used to verify that the password entered is correct, I believe that it is not necessary to save it as it will be the same as the password already saved by default. Your goal should be to display an error message when the passwords are different.

Comment: @Vdgaetano, Yes, you are right. I have to show only an error message. I have to only verify the password.

Comment: @user9437856 Try adding `return $errors;` to the end of the `confirmmpassword_validate_fields` function.

Comment: @Vdgaetano, I comment out the confirmpassword_save_register_fields and added return $errors; after the closing if condition in the confirmpassword_validate_fields (as you suggested). Now I added password: Pass#@123456 and confirm password: 1 and form submitted. It should display the error message. right?